# weird white spaces in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I saw this weird regex in javascript.

```
string = "abababababababa";
string=string.replace(/ ?a ?/g,"X");
alert(string);
```

I ran it , and the output I got was all a replaced by X
What is puzzling is the white spaces in the regex. I delete the first white space, the script won't run. I delete the 2nd white space, I get one "a" replaced by two "X"s.
I wonder how it works.

Comment: Pro-tip: use an [online regex editor](http://regex101.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The space actually means to match a space character (U+0020).

The key is the [`?` quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) that follows each of them, allowing the pattern to match "*0 or 1 spaces*" for each, essentially making them *optional*.

So, the `/ ?a ?/` pattern is capable of matching:

- `"a"`
- `"a "`
- `" a"`
- `" a "`

And, attempting to remove either space will change the meaning of the pattern:

- Removing the leading space (`/?a ?/g`) actually results in a `SyntaxError` as quantifiers require something before them to quantify.
- Removing the trailing space (`/ ?a?/g`) is syntactically valid, but the `?` quantifier will then apply to the `a`, changing the possible matches to:

  - `""`
  - `"a"`
  - `" "`
  - `" a"`

Comment: And, crucially, the space and its quantifier are one "atom" in the regex, so should not be split in half. Deleting the first space leaves a `?` quantifier with nothing to quantify (hence the script fails); deleting the second space attaches a `?` quantifier to the `a`, making the rather odd pattern of "maybe a space, then maybe an `a`".

Comment: Ah, I see. I have never seen this way of matching a space character before (instead of \s). Thank you guys for the helps!

Answer (score 4):

the `?` character makes the spaces optional in matching.

For example, these strings will be replaced with an X with that regular expression.

```
> "a"
> " a"
> " a "
> "a "
```

You can find more information about this quantifier **[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)**.

Answer (score 4):

`' '` is matching an actual space character. The `?` quantifier means **Match** `1` or `0` times.

Your regular expression does the following:

```
 ?          ' ' optional space character
a           match 'a'
 ?          ' ' optional space character
```

It will match the following cases:

- `'a'`
- `'a '`
- `' a'`
- `' a '`

You regular expression will match `a`b`a`b`a`b`a`b`a`b`a`b`a`b`a` in your input string using the `g` (global modifier). Meaning all matches (don't return on first match)

- If you remove the space character at the beginning the preceding token is not quantifiable so it will **fail**.
- If you leave the space character but remove the first `?` it will **fail** because it looks to match a space character, however a space character does not exist in the input.
- If you remove the second space character, it still succeeds the match making `a` optional here.